# multi-threaded sort

Tags: multithreading, sorting

Is there a multi-threaded version of the standard `sort` command? I'm looking for something that would take as input a maximum number of threads to use, possibly a given amount of RAM, plus the standard `sort` options, and just run.

Comment: There are multithreaded sorting algorithms, many of which are quite good.  If your question is about how to learn more about these algorithms, could you rephrase the question to more explicitly ask that?  If your question is about what libraries already support these sorting algorithms, can you rephrase the question to have more details about what language you're using?

Comment: Unless you have a compare function that burns lot of cpu cycles, sorting is RAM bus bound.  Threads don't buy your more busses.

Comment: I'm talking about a drop-in replacement of the standard linux `sort` command which could make use of multiple threads. For example, I recently found a multi-threaded version of `gzip`, which just works.

Comment: @typedef: As bad as that might sound, I'm not looking to learn them. Were any of those implemented in a way that could be used to just replace command-line sort, without excessive effort?

Comment: @Hans: Do you have a reference for your statement? I don't have a clear idea how one would measure that. If the basic comparison is non-trivial (e.g., multiple key/string comparison) and takes a few cycles even in the closest cache, couldn't those cycles be used to prefetch other records, and maybe process them with a second thread?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `sort` command was parallelized in `coreutils-8.6` which was released on 2010-10-15. Here's the commit where it was added:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=9face836f36c507f01a7d7a33138c5a303e3b1df

However, I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 which is still on `coreutils-8.5`. I don't know when the new `sort` will make its way into most distros.